# OpenSSH shows a version of OpenSSL but openssl version -v shows the new version i have installed in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl

I have a server Ubuntu 14.04 which initially had OpenSSH 6.6 and OpenSSL 1.0.1f installed, and with these commands, i updated openSSH:

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
wget "https://mirror.edgecast.com/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.4p1.tar.gz"
tar xfz openssh-7.4p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-7.4p1
./configure
make
sudo make install && sudo service ssh restart && ssh -V
```

After that, i have an output of:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f
```

The thing is that i have updated openSSL separately after that, with these commands:

```
sudo wget "https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2n.tar.gz"
tar xfz openssl-1.0.2n.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2n/
./config
make
sudo make install
```

After that, i run: `openssl version` and i get:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2n
```

but `ssh -V` shows:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f
```

Is there a way of having ssh -V returning OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you rebuild OpenSSH *after* updating OpenSSL ? According to the steps you posted, you did *not*.

Comment: Hi @WhozCraig, which commands should i run to accomplish that? Thank you

Comment: The steps to build OpenSSH are already in your *question*. You already did it once. Clean it and do it again. It may well be as simple as going back to that OpenSSH build root, obliterating everything but the .tar.gz file, and repeating the last five steps you did before.

Comment: I have reproduced those steps after installing OpenSSH, but ssh -V is still showing 1.0.1 version of OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System need to know where the new version of openssl is, try :

```
cd openssl-1.0.2n/
./config --prefix=/usr/local --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl shared
make clean && make && make install
openssl version
echo "/usr/local/ssl/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
ldconfig -v

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```

Then `cd` into openssh directory, clean and rebuild.

Comment: Thank you @Philippe! I´ve run those commands you mentioned above, and that solved the issue. Thank you again for sharing knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

As per OpenSSH INSTALL instructions: [openssh-portable/INSTALL at V_7_4_P1 · openssh/openssh-portable · GitHub](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_7_4_P1/INSTALL#L19-L20):

```
LibreSSL/OpenSSL should be compiled as a position-independent library
(i.e. with -fPIC) otherwise OpenSSH will not be able to link with it.
```

Update your OpenSSL `./config` command to include `-fPIC no-shared`:

```
sudo wget "https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2n.tar.gz"
tar xfz openssl-1.0.2n.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2n/
./config -fPIC no-shared
make
sudo make install
```

You may have to run `make clean && make dclean` before recompiling and installing OpenSSL.